# Where to get accesses for the DHL shipping method?

Tags: configuration, dhl

To enable it, I need:

Access ID

Password

Account Number

[image: admin panel]

Answer (score 2):

You need to go to the DHL website and register an account in order to receive an Access ID, Password and Account Number:

http://www.dhl-usa.com/en/express/shipping/open_account.html

Comment: is account paid ?